# Read CSV and find fill rate of each column

Tags: java, opencsv

I have to read the CSV file and calculate the fill rate of each column in a CSV file. I am reading a CSV file that looks like the following:

```
Roll No, Name,  Department
1      , Person1,  CS
2      , Person2,  CS
3      , Person3,  CS
       , Person4,  CS
null   ,        ,  null
```

Now as we can see the column **Roll No** does not contains data after 3rd row so its fill rate would be 80%
and for column **Name** the fill rate would be 90% because there is no data in a 5th row and so on for the rest of the columns in a CSV file.

I want the output to be something like:

```
{
  "fillRate": [
    {
      "columnName": "Roll No",
      "fillRate": "80%"
    },
    {
      "columnName": "Name",
      "fillRate": "90%"
    },
    {
      "columnName": "Department",
      "fillRate": "90%"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is my code so far:

```
readFile(String fileName){
        String fullPath= fileDir + "/" + fileName;
        int totalNumOfRows=0;
        int totalNumOfRowsExcludeHeader=0;
        String[] headers = null;
        String[] columnsValue;
        Map<String,Integer> headerAndValidRecord = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
        Map<String,Integer> headerAndPercentageOfValidRecord = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
        List<Map<String,String>> responeList= new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
        try{
            InputStream in = sftpConnection.get(fullPath);// getting File from server
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));


            String line = null;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){

                totalNumOfRows++;
                
                if(totalNumOfRows==1){
                    headers =line.split(",");
                    for(int h=0;h<headers.length;h++){
                        headerAndValidRecord.put(headers[h], 0);
                    }
                }
                

                
                else{
                    columnsValue =line.split(",");

                    for(int cV=0;cV<columnsValue.length;cV++){

                        if((columnsValue[cV]!=null) && (!((columnsValue[cV].trim()).isEmpty()))){
                            int countOfValidRecord=0;
                            countOfValidRecord=headerAndValidRecord.get(headers[cV]);
                            countOfValidRecord=countOfValidRecord+1;
                            headerAndValidRecord.put(headers[cV], countOfValidRecord);
                        }
                    }//--For loop close.
                }
                
            } 
            totalNumOfRowsExcludeHeader=totalNumOfRows-1;
            );
            headerAndPercentageOfValidRecord=calculatePercentage(headerAndValidRecord,totalNumOfRowsExcludeHeader); 
            
            
            
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responeList;
     }
```

Comment: Dear @GhostChat many thanks for your help. :)

Comment: I appreciate you coming back and improving your input!

Comment: What is still missing: please explain what you think your current code is doing, and where the actual results deviate from your your expectations. Also note: you should separate concerns. It really doesnt matter that you want to create a JSON record **after** computing those numbers. Focus on one problem at the time. Your 1st problem: reading the CSV data, and computing the **correct** percentages. When that works, you can do whatever you want with that. So, as said: drop the parts that do not matter to your question, and instead explain what you think is missing, and why/where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try (total_filled/total_column) * 100.

Comment: Probably because the OP didnt think about that so far ... as their code doesnt contain any attempts to count values per column .... and note: your input would be an okay comment, but it really doesnt constitute an answer. You would have to explain *how* to compute these values, and so on.